# Problemas com ComboBox

Tags: c#, mysql

Eu estou desenvolvendo um software que cataloga mangás. Nele você tem a opção de selecionar 2 genêros para o mangá. Os generos são carregados em uma ComboBox a partir de uma tabela de MySql e quando o usuário cadastra o mangá o gênero da ComboBox é gravado na tabela do mangá.

No Formulário eu tenho 2 ComboBox, um para cada genêro, porém os valores não ficam, se eu seleciono um valor na **cmbGenero1** esse valor fica marcado na **cmbGenero2**.

Essas foram todas as vezes que as ComboBox foram citadas no código:

```
private void inserirCmbGenero()
{
    con.Open();
    MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand();
    comando.Connection = con;
    comando.CommandText = "SELECT Genero FROM tblGenero";
    MySqlDataReader dr = comando.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(dr);
    cmbGenero1.DisplayMember = "Genero";
    cmbGenero1.DataSource = dt;
    cmbGenero2.DisplayMember = "Genero";
    cmbGenero2.DataSource = dt;
    con.Close();
}

private void frmCadastro_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    inserirCmbMangaka();
    inserirCmbGenero();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está usando o mesmo contexto para os dois combobox. Precisa de um contexto pra cada um. Veja sobre isto [aqui.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.bindingcontext?view=netframework-4.8) e uma resposta no SO [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344366/multiple-combo-boxes-with-the-same-data-source-c#answer-10239016)

Abaixo a solução para seu problema.

> **USANDO O cmbGenero2.BindingContext = new BindingContext();**

```
private void inserirCmbGenero()
{
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder sConnB = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
    {
            DataSource = "MYSERVER",
            InitialCatalog = "Testes",
            UserID = "user_tst",
            Password = "user_tst"
    };


    using (var con = new SqlConnection(sConnB.ConnectionString))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand();
        comando.Connection = con;
        comando.CommandText = "SELECT ID_GENERO, DESC_GENERO FROM TBLGENERO";
        SqlDataReader dr = comando.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);
        cmbGenero1.DisplayMember = "DESC_GENERO";
        cmbGenero1.ValueMember = "ID_GENERO";
        cmbGenero1.DataSource = dt;

        cmbGenero2.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
        cmbGenero2.DisplayMember = "DESC_GENERO";
        cmbGenero2.ValueMember = "ID_GENERO";
        cmbGenero2.DataSource = dt;

    }

}
```

Comment: Vlw mano, deu certo aqui. Se tu quiser me avisa que te passo o software quando ficar pronto.